# "Invalid use of null" for OpenArgs when calling OpenForm

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I cannot find the reason but I keep getting an invalid use of null when using OpenArgs

The code is set up with

```
Private Sub cmdContactDetails_Click()
    Dim ArgsString As String

    ArgsString = Forms!LeadList![Entrepreneur Name] & "," & Forms!LeadList![Telephone Number] & "," & Forms!LeadList![Email Address]
    DoCmd.OpenForm "ContactDetails", , , , , , ArgsString
End Sub
```

This results in the string "X,123456789,test@test"

In the Form_Open event of contact details I have:

```
Dim SaveString As String  
SaveString = Forms!ContactDetails.OpenArgs
```

But this gives me an "Invalid Use of Null" message even though nothing is null.

Comment: What do you see if you add `MsgBox Nz(Me.OpenArgs, "nothing")` before anything else in Form Open?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a form named:- "LeadList"

and the form also has a text box named:- "Entrepreneur_Name"

and this form contains the following code:-

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdContactDetails_Click()
Dim ArgsString As String

    ArgsString = Me.Entrepreneur_Name
    DoCmd.OpenForm "ContactDetails", , , , , , ArgsString

End Sub
```

The above code is called via a command button named "cmdContactDetails" on the form named:- "LeadList" then the form "ContactDetails" will be opened **(form "ContactDetails" must be closed first)** and the on open event will run this code:-

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Dim SaveString As String

    SaveString = Forms!ContactDetails.OpenArgs
    MsgBox " >>> " & SaveString

End Sub
```

The message box will display the contents of the text transferred via the open args function from the form "LeadList" text box "Entrepreneur_Name"